# Regex split sentence into multiple groups

Tags: regex, vb.net, split

Regex Expression for sentence split needed.
I need a Regex approach to split a sentence up.
The following sentence structure needs to be broken into its component parts:

Question, Options, AnswerType divided by the following delimiters...

```
Question :  OptionA, OptionB, OptionC   ?   AnswerType

EXAMPLES:
Color: Yellow, Green, Red ? ListBox
Color ? ListBox
```

As you can see, the second example has no options and this needs to be accounted for. 
The output would ideally look like the following groups

I am working in VB.NET if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how regex works in vb.net but here's a general patter and well explained in the [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fM7jB8)

Regex:

`(?P<question>\w+)\s*(?::\s*(?P<options>\w+(?:,\s*\w+)*))?\s*\?\s*(?P<type>\w+)`

The ?P< name> determines a name for backreferencing that group,  you would just loop and you will have everything grouped.

Try out the new regex with the (suffix): [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vO9yR4) I just added the possibility of having (sufix) after the question.

The Updated regex:

`(?P<question>\w+)\s*(?P<suffix>\(\w+\))?\s*(?::\s*(?P<options>\w+(?:,\s*\w+)*))?\s*\?\s*(?P<type>\w+)`

UPDATE 2: Working with spaces and `'` -> `(?P<question>[\w '-]+)\s*(?P<suffix>\([\w '-]+\))?\s*(?::\s*(?P<options>[\w '-]+(?:,\s*[\w '-]+)*))?\s*\?\s*(?P<type>[\w '-]+)`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pZ2zY6)

Comment: thanks  this looks great except I think VB.NEt must use a different flavor as it is giving me error " Unrecognized grouping construct." Looks like the P after the ? is causing trouble.

Comment: Success! I dropped the P after the ? and it works perfect in VB.NET. DEMO web site is fantastic!  Thanks!

Comment: Javier: How about if I wanted to add an additional optional Group called "suffix" that would be enclosed in() after the Question group.                EXAMPLES:                                                       Size(mm): Yellow, Green, Red ?ListBox                             Size: Small, Medium, Large ? List                                    Age(yrs)? ListBox

Comment: And how do you want that to be retrieved?

Comment: If you dont want to backreference the ( and ), tell me.

Comment: <suffix> is perfect for backreference name

Comment: Looks great but would like to add capability to handle some spaces, extra characters and hypentaed words as the example shows below to accomodate user typographical imperfections....                                     Shirmer's Test  (cm): Small Guy , Medium- Large ,  Extra-Large   ?  Text

Comment: Add another example as EDIT in your post so I can see what you want to do.

Comment: Shirmer's Test (cm): Small Guy , Medium- Large , Extra-Large ? Text